# How to access function handles in a cell array?

Tags: matlab, cell-array, function-handle

```
rate_arr_cst_1 = @(t) 2*sin(t)+10; 
rate_arr_cst_2 = @(t) 3*sin(2*t)+8;
rate_arr_cst_h = {rate_arr_cst_1, rate_arr_cst_2};
```

I defined a cell array in such way and try to access in the following way:

```
i=1;
h = rate_arr_cst_h(i);
```

but what I get here is still a cell array, meaning i can't use h to evaluate t=0.1.

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use a for loop:

```
for ii = 1:numel(rate_arr_cst_h)
    hh(ii) = rate_arr_cst_h{ii}(i);
end
```

or you can use `cellfun`:

```
hh = cellfun(@(f) f(i), rate_arr_cst_h);
```

Comment: If any of the answers has solved your problem, please kindly accept it by clicking on the tick mark besides the answer. If not, please drop a comment so people knows you need further help on specific problem.

Answer (score 4):

When you do `h = rate_arr_cst_h(i);`, you are accessing the `i^th` element of the cell array, which is still a cell. If you want to access the contents of `i^th` cell in the cell array, you need to do: `h = rate_arr_cst_h{i};`. Note the use of curly brackets.